Is there any way to automatically redirect to the IdP sign-in page when open protected page in Next.js with Auth.js
I'm developing a web site with Next.js@14.2.2 and Auth.js(next-auth@5.0.0-beta.16).
I have already configured the provider with the following code, I can sign in with "Sign in" button correctly.
auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Cognito from 'next-auth/providers/cognito'

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [Cognito],
})

app/login/page.tsx
import { auth, signIn } from '@/auth'

export default async function Login() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        'use server'
        return await signIn('cognito')
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  )
}

Problems
I want to use middleware to protect all pages and redirect to Amazon cognito(IdP) sign-in page automatically.
However, the following code does not work. (Stay protected page without session and does not redirect)
Is there any way to redirect to the Cognito sign-in page?
Note: Already I can redirect to /login in my application, but I want to remove a redundant click for the user.
middleware
import { signIn, auth } from "@/auth"

export default auth((request) => {
  if (!request.auth) {
    signIn('cognito')
  }
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|login).*)"],
}

error log
ReadonlyRequestCookiesError: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at Proxy.callable (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies.js:22:15)
    at signIn (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:53:65)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: ReadonlyRequestCookiesError: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at Proxy.callable (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies.js:22:15)
    at signIn (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:53:65)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: ReadonlyRequestCookiesError: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at Proxy.callable (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies.js:22:15)
    at signIn (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:53:65)
 GET / 200 in 46ms


the error is:

Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.

I think you're encountering this error because you tried to perform signIn inside of a server-component. You can only get cookies on the server side but can't set or delete them on the server. make your signin component as a client component and the error will be gone.
now, coming to your required middleware behavior, if you want to protect routes on middleware level, you need to pass an array of your protected routes to  the middleware and then match the current pathname with each of the pathnames of protected_route_array and in this way, your routes will be protected.
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
  const protectedRoutes=['/route1', '/route2' ];
  const token = await getToken({ req: request });
  if (token == null && protectedRoutes.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        "/signin",
        request.url
      )
    );
  }
}


Sorry I didn't tell about this method, but redirect to /api/auth/signin will display cognito button to select IdP. An redundant click can't be removed.

Can you share any repo link or docs link with which I can regenerate the issue?
